# Test http 404 error responses in Angular 7

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have an api endpoint that returns a 404 error for a search when there are no results. I have used catchError in the Angular service to return an empty array in this case. This works when running the application, however I am trying to write a test case for it and it never hits the catchError block. What am I missing ??

Service Code:

```
  public searchStuff(query: SearchQuery): Observable<Array<Stuff>> {
    const url: string = `${this.appConfig.baseUrl}/stuffs?title=${query.searchTerm}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<Stuff>>(url).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('made request')),
      map(data => data.map(stuff => new Stuff(stuff)),
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          console.log('Not Found');
          return of(new Array<Stuff>());
        }

        throw error;
      })
    ));
  }
```

Test:

```
  it('should handle a 404 when no search results are found', inject([HttpTestingController], (mockController: HttpTestingController) => {
    const service: SearchService = TestBed.get(SearchService);

    const query: SearchQuery = new SearchQuery();
    query.searchFor = 'stuffs';
    query.searchTerm = 'something';

    service.searchWorks(query).subscribe(results => {
      expect(results).toBeDefined();
    });

    const req = mockController.expectOne(request => {
      return request.url === 'http://localhost/stuffs?title=something' && request.method === 'GET';
    });

    const errorEvent: ErrorEvent = new ErrorEvent('Not Found');
    req.error(errorEvent, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found'});
    // req.flush(null, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found ' });
    mockController.verify();
  }));
```

I have a positive test which calls `req.flush([])`, this does `console.log('made request')` where as the 404 above test doesn't.

Comment: Also you should put your assert in the error part of your subscription. You are returning error, but checking the next() callback alone.

Comment: @KiraAG that would be a standard assertion to make, however I am expecting the 404 to be suppressed and an empty array returned from the service.

Comment: Can you remove tap and check?  actually tap doesn’t return anything, you should return from tap to be propagated to map operator.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the order of operators is key in this scenario. catchError must come before map and all both application and spec seem to work.

```
  public searchStuff(query: SearchQuery): Observable<Array<Stuff>> {
    const url: string = `${this.appConfig.baseUrl}/stuffs?title=${query.searchTerm}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<Stuff>>(url).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('made request')),
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          console.log('Not Found');
          return of(new Array<Stuff>());
        }

        throw error;
      }),
      map(data => data.map(stuff => new Stuff(stuff))
    ));
  }
```